# Unique letters in alphabet

Tags: python

I want to write a simple text classifier by languages using unique letters, just for experiment.
For example, I have `alphabet` for each language as a dict of sets with the following keys: `['ru', 'uk', 'pl', 'en', 'de', 'be', ...]`. 
For example, unique Polish letters are "ę" and "ś", English doesn't have unique ones.
In fact, I should find all letters that don't belong to others languages. I did it like this (simple example):

```
alphabets = {'it': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'à', 'ì'},
             'en': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
             'pl': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'ę', 'ś'}}

def union_others(except_lang):
    res = set()
    for lang in alphabets:    
        if lang != except_lang:
            res = res | alphabets[lang]
   return res

unique = {lang: set() for lang in alphabets}
for lang in alphabets:
    unique[lang] = alphabets[lang] - union_others(lang)

print(unique['pl'])
```

I get the following output: `{'ę', 'ś'}`

Is there any simple way (without cycle) to get a union of all sets of languages except the current one instead of using `union_others(lang)` function?

Comment: This is not related to machine learning or natural language processing in any way.

Comment: How do you expect to do this without looping? That would imply that you aren't looking at all the inputs.

Comment: If you are worried specifically about python for loops, that's another matter. You could probably get away with loops only being there under the hood.

Comment: The main loop (inside `res | alphabets[lang]`) is under the hood here.

Comment: @Mad Physicist I expect syntax something like this `set.union(*map(set, list_of_lists))` which unites lists in set.

Comment: @MorisHuxley, so you are looking for more compact (and less readable) syntax rather then efficiency?

Comment: @Mad Physicist efficiency is more important for me.

Comment: Another thing you might want to call `casefold` on each of your characters to ensure that you always compare the same things across languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't get away from a loop entirely, but you can make it slightly more efficient using short circuiting. In most cases, languages won't have any truly unique characters, so you can  break out of your loop early, effectively avoiding the construction of the full set of other languages every time:

```
def delta(lang):
    d = set(alphabets[lang]) # make a copy
    for key, alphabet in alphabets.items():
        if key == lang:
            continue
        d -= alphabet
        if not d:
            break
    return d

unique = {lang: delta(lang) for lang in alphabets}
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/lcRfxX)

This will be a bit faster also because the set you are subtracting from has fewer elements almost immediately, speeding up the difference operation even further.

Now if you had some a-priori knowledge about the similarity of languages, you could use it to pre-sort `alphabets` for each language so that it's unique set would be reduced to a minimum almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions.

```
alphabets = {'it': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'à', 'ì'},
             'en': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
             'pl': {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'ę', 'ś'}}

def f(k, d):
    #return [x for x in d[k] if any(x not in v for k,v in d.items())]
    return {x for x in d[k] if any(x not in v for k,v in d.items())}


print(f('pl', alphabets))
print(f('en', alphabets))
print(f('it', alphabets))
```

Comment: Your solution looks better then mine. It's shorter

Answer (score -1):

You could create a set which is a combination of all of the languages.

Then you could get the differences between this large set and the English set to get the unique values.

Of course, you would need some sort of iterative method to create the large set.

EDIT: This is assuming that the language you want to exclude is English. If it's another language, then you need to get the differences between the large set and the set of your said language. If you want all languages, then you should follow this process for each language and loop through the languages.

Comment: That wouldn't work. You would have to create a large set for each language, excluding that language.

Comment: OP is asking for all the languages.

Comment: Oh it works fine. It's just not a reasonable solution for what OP is asking.